# Alignment issue with css

Tags: html, css

I want the header to look alike [coreLogic](http://www.corelogic.com). But there is some alignment issues with mine. Here is the link http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/internetbrands.html. How to solve this issue??

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: on the right corner of the header, there should be a nav list and a bg img. For some reason bg img is not displaying. More over I see a mysterious  vertical line there.

Comment: can you put your code up on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your i-brands.css file:

```
#header .utility 
{
background: url("../images/utility-nav.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
}
```

Taking out the -200px put the image up and took out the line.  I tested it.

Also, get [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) if possible.  You could have figured this out for yourself in two seconds.  Keep on truckin sir.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an alignment issue. CoreLogic is using a CSS sprite to display the background image. That's why they have used -200px and other as position values.

Note: I wanted this to be a comment but I don't see an option to add comment to OP's post.

Comment: You need more rep to get the comment anywhere privilege.  Hover over your name when signed in.  You will see a privilege link in the jquery box that fades in.  That will show you how close you are.